# mouseJoint doesn't grab object in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, box2d

i looked around and i found similar issues but in java environment (where I'm totally unprepared).
I created some bodies in my world and now i am making a mouse joint to make them moving, but even if the body seems to be selected and the joint created, i cannot grab it at all;

here is the code in my .mm file

```
class myQueryCallback: public b2QueryCallback
{


public:
    myQueryCallback(const b2Vec2& point)
    {
    mouse_p = point;
    body = nil;
}

bool ReportFixture(b2Fixture* fixture)
{


    body = fixture->GetBody();
    body = nil;

    if (fixture->GetBody()->GetType() != b2_staticBody || nil)

    {
        bool inside = fixture->TestPoint(mouse_p);
        if (inside)
        {

            body = fixture->GetBody();
            trackerBody = body;
            if (trackerBody != nil ){touchedCheck = 1;
                //myfunctionhere();
            }
            m_fixture = fixture;
            return false;

        }
    }
    m_fixture = fixture;
    trackerBody = body;
    return true;
}
b2Body* body;
b2Vec2  mouse_p;
b2Fixture* m_fixture;

};
```

...

```
/*-(void) registerWithTouchDispatcher
{

    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] touchDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0 swallowsTouches:NO];
}*/
```

i found this part in a tutorial but as it's active the program crashes and quit

```
- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event // grab objects
{

for( UITouch *touch in touches ) {
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];

    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: location];

    b2Vec2 myTouchPos;
    myTouchPos.Set(location.x/PTM_RATIO, location.y/PTM_RATIO);

    b2AABB aabb;
    b2Vec2 correction;
    correction.Set(0.001f, 0.001f);
    aabb.lowerBound = myTouchPos - correction;
    aabb.upperBound = myTouchPos + correction;

    // Query the world for overlapping shapes.
    myQueryCallback ReportFixture(myTouchPos);
    world->QueryAABB(&ReportFixture, aabb);


    if (ReportFixture.m_fixture)
    {
        b2Body* myBody = ReportFixture.m_fixture->GetBody();
        b2MouseJointDef md;

        md.bodyA = ground1;//currentGround;
        md.bodyB = myBody;
        md.target = myTouchPos;
        md.maxForce = 2000.0f * myBody->GetMass();

        mouseJoint = (b2MouseJoint*)world->CreateJoint(&md);
        myBody->SetAwake(true);
        NSValue *mouseJointVal = [NSValue valueWithPointer:mouseJoint];
        NSLog(@"mouseJoint %@",mouseJointVal);
```

till here NSLog displays my pointer but i cannot grab the b2Body i chose

```
    }

}
}


   - (void)ccTouchEnded:(UITouch*)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
   {
        if(mouseJoint)
    {

    world->DestroyJoint(mouseJoint);
    mouseJoint = nil;
    NSValue *mouseJointVal = [NSValue valueWithPointer:mouseJoint];
    NSLog(@"mouseJoint ended %@",mouseJointVal); 

    }
}
```

this part doesn't seem to work, NSLog doesn't display anything in console

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not show the code for your ccTouchesMoved, but I will assume that you know the mouse joint must have its target location moved when the touch moves, otherwise nothing will happen.

I'm not sure exactly what the cause of the problem is, but there are a few problems I do see. Maybe it will help to point them out.

The first is that you are looping through potentially multiple touch points in ccTouchesBegan. If more than one touch starts at the same time, you will create more than one mouse joint and only the last created joint will be stored in the 'mousejoint' variable.

The second is that in ccTouchesEnded you are destroying the joint when *any* touch ends - you should be checking if the touch is the same touch that created the mouse joint.

The third is that your ReportFixture function in the callback is setting the 'm_fixture' member for all reported fixtures, regardless of whether they are dynamic or not. A mouse joint should have one dynamic body, so rather than checking if the body is not static (it might also be kinematic), you should check that it *is* dynamic.

Finally, the value of 'm_fixture' in the query callback is not initialized to anything, so if no fixtures are reported you will end up using garbage data in that pointer and probably crash when trying to dereference it.

The only reason I can think of that the NSLog in ccTouchesBegan shows, but the NSLog in ccTouchesEnded does not show, is that the variable 'mousejoint' is not the same (eg. variable shadowing).

I am also assuming that you are rendering the touched positions somehow to check that the position you touch is actually being converted to physics coordinates correctly. Otherwise it's possible that your touch is detecting a different fixture to the one you think it is (eg. another offscreen fixture), which might explain why you don't see anything happening.

Comment: Thank you again for the complete answer, I'm still new at all this; I'll proceed with fixing all these issues and I will let you know

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved everything thanks to the right advices, but I'm writing these lines down hoping they can help who's a newbie like me about xcode + box2d and needs some code sample:

at first I avoided the "for" loop, which was just messing up the stuff, as suggested, plus I changed my ccTouchBegan method from "void" to "bool" and I set it up like this:

```
-(BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch*)touch withEvent:(UIEvent*)event // grab objects
{

    //select body at location

    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: location];

    b2Vec2 myTouchPos;
    myTouchPos.Set(location.x/PTM_RATIO, location.y/PTM_RATIO);

    if (mouseJoint != NULL)
    {
        return NO;
    }

    b2AABB aabb;
    b2Vec2 correction;
    correction.Set(0.001f, 0.001f);
    aabb.lowerBound = myTouchPos - correction;
    aabb.upperBound = myTouchPos + correction;

    // Query the world for overlapping shapes.
    myQueryCallback ReportFixture(myTouchPos);
    world->QueryAABB(&ReportFixture, aabb);


    if (ReportFixture.m_fixture)
    {
        b2Body* myBody = ReportFixture.m_fixture->GetBody();
        trackerBody = myBody;
        b2MouseJointDef md;

        md.bodyA = ground1;
        md.bodyB = trackerBody;
        md.target = myTouchPos;
        md.maxForce = 2000.0f * trackerBody->GetMass();

        mouseJoint = (b2MouseJoint*)world->CreateJoint(&md);
        trackerBody->SetAwake(true);

        NSLog(@"mouseJoint created, myBody %f x, %f y",trackerBody->GetPosition().x,trackerBody->GetPosition().y);
        return YES;

    }

    return YES;
}
```

after this the touchDispatcher didn’t make any crash anymore, so I could implement it successfully and the mouseJoint finally looks correct and sent correct values also in logs; also it fixed the ccTouchMoved and the ccTouchEnded method, which were both already correct, but couldn't work due to the not implemented touchDispatcher.

I also set the check for the m_fixture as equal to b2_dynamicBody and it's a lot better.

this:

```
if (fixture->GetBody()->GetType() == b2_dynamicBody || nil
```

instead of this:

```
if (fixture->GetBody()->GetType() != b2_staticBody || nil
```

In the end when I checked my .mm file i found out that I had accidentally removed my update (Tick()) method, so even if the mouseJoint was working that explained why I wasn’t able yet to see my bodies moving, due to the screen’s refresh loss…

after implementing this again:

```
-(void) update: (ccTime) dt
    {
    int32 velocityIterations = 8;
    int32 positionIterations = 1;

    world->Step(dt, velocityIterations, positionIterations);
    }
```

everything started to work perfectly.

Thanks a lot again for the help!